# How can I update random value of radius after every cycle?

Tags: java, javafx, random

Here is my following code:

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 600);
        Random rand = new Random();

       int random = rand.nextInt(100-5)+5;
       Circle circle = new Circle(0, 10, random);
       circle.setFill(Color.RED);
       root.getChildren().add(circle);

       Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
              Duration.seconds(2),
              new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), 600)
         ));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
        timeline.play();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

In this code it only update the `random` value once, but I want it to update `random` value after each cycle. Is there any way I can update my `random` value after each cycle? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` that updates the `radius` property to the last `KeyFrame` of the `Timeline`:

```
final Random rand = new Random();

int random = rand.nextInt(100-5)+5;
final Circle circle = new Circle(0, 10, random);
circle.setFill(Color.RED);
root.getChildren().add(circle);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(
      Duration.seconds(2),
      event -> circle.setRadius(rand.nextInt(100-5)+5),
      new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), 600)
 ));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: I wanna do that for `getStrokeDashArray.addAll(x, y, z)` I wanna change the value of x, y, z as well for `Line`. Is it possible I can do it with `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`?

Comment: You can do anything in the event handler that could be done from outside the method. Note that `addAll` may not be the proper method to call, since this will add more and more elements. `setAll` may be the method you're looking for. Moreover you could of course use multiple statements in the lambda expression by surrounding them with `{}`: `event -> { ... your statements go here... }` or you could instead use any class implementing `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` to handle the event should this better suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)

> It is not possible to change the keyFrames of a running Timeline. If
>   the value of keyFrames is changed for a running Timeline, it has to be
>   stopped and started again to pick up the new value.

So, you can recreate the timeline everytime you want to create a new keyFrame, in your case with a `new Circle(0, 10, new Random().nextInt(100-5)+5, Color.RED);`

Comment: @Hemlata The answer is not that line of code, but *you can recreate the timeline everytime you want to create a new keyFrame*.. how to do it is something that you must try.

Comment: But, I don't know how to recreate a timeline. It is appreciated if you can help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor for Keyframe which takes multiple KeyValue. You can add to the constructor a new KeyValue with the radius of circle. As far as I can see you should create your own implementation of Interpolator to make alive the random behaviour for the radius. (Maybe there are third party solutions for that)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` to your call to the KeyValue constructor.
That is, add a parameter to `new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), 600)` so it looks something like `new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), (event)->{circle.setRadius(rand.nextInt(100-5)+5);}, 600)`

Comment: I can't do that as int is not compatible with interpolator

Answer (score 1):

The default Interpolater(EASE_BOTH) clamps the value of time for current interval i.e. frac value will range from [0.0, ... , 1.0]. You can use the same information and update the radius at the beginning of the new cycle.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 600);

    final Random random = new Random();
    Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, random.nextInt(100));
    circle.setFill(Color.RED);
    root.getChildren().add(circle);

    Animation animation = new Transition() {
        {
            setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);
            setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        }

        @Override
        protected void interpolate(double frac) {
            if (frac == 0) {
                final int newRadius = random.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println("New Radius: " + newRadius);
                circle.setRadius(newRadius + 5);
            }
            circle.setTranslateX(frac * 600);
        }
    };
    animation.play();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `interpolate` will be called with parameter `0` at the start of each cycle and it will remain to be implemented this way? Something like `interpolate(((currentTime - startTime) / duration) % 1d)` could be used as well (haven't taken a look at the source code though).

Comment: It may change if the implemented Interpolator changes. For the default interpolater i.e. EASE_BOTH, it should work fine. I will update the answer with the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will slow down your code, but you might want to try setting cycle count to 1 instead of Animation.INDEFINITE and wrapping the entire block in a while loop:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 600);
    Random rand = new Random();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    while (true) { 
        int random = rand.nextInt(100-5)+5;
        Circle circle = new Circle(0, 10, random);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(2),
            new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), 600)
        ));
        timeline.setCycleCount(1);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(false);

        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

One issue is that the primaryStage.show() will get moved up (so that it still runs despite the forever loop). Consider changing the `while (true)` to something else if this becomes a problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I run it, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: This not even does this not work, it creates more and more circles/timelines until you either run out of memory or out of indices for the child list of root. Furthermore `play()` only schedules the animation to start, but returns immediately. Seriously, why was this upvoted???